# Should an aggregate data item have the same name as a detail data item?

Tags: sql, naming-conventions, data-warehouse, dimensional-modeling

Consider the following SQL:

```
   select dimension, sum(fact) as fact
   from t
   group by dimension;
```

Here, I have given the aggregated fact the same name as the granular, un-aggregated fact. Is this considered a good or a bad idea?

Pro: the aggregated data item is, in all ways save its dimension, the "same type of" data item as the detailed data item.

Con: Because of the dimensional difference, it is nevertheless *not* the same type of data item, and care should be taken when combining it with other data items - therefore it is best to distinguish it by calling it something like fact_agg.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I always prefix with the aggregation name, so in your case `SumFact`.  This is important if you have multiple aggregations on the same fact, such as:

```
Select Dimension, 
       COUNT(Fact) as CountFact, 
       SUM(Fact) as SumFact, 
       AVG(Fact) as AvgFact
from t
group by Dimension
```